# Display remains black after resuming from suspend

Tags: 16.04, suspend, amd-graphics

I've seen others with this question but no answer helped me.

I use Ubuntu 16.04 on a fairly old laptop using an ATI graphics card.

Upon resuming, if the lid is **closed** (And was closed during the suspend), then the screen remains black.

If the lid was **open**, it works fine.

This leads me to think the problem is not all to do with my graphics drivers (which are the default).

**EDIT:** This previously worked on Ubuntu 12.04 with no issues.

Comment: Unfortunately the Suspend option has different quirks per machine, particular older hardware. And not many old videocards can handle powerdowns/ups well. I suggest you use Hibernate instead of Suspend to see if that is an improvement.

Comment: @WillemK Hibernate does work better for me, but takes longer to power up and down.

Comment: @WillemK please see edit.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have more suggestions other than using Hibernate. I have no ATI in my system so i cannot replay your situation.